# Convert child location to parent location coordinates

Tags: python, math, coordinates

I have a bigger area where there are smaller parts inside. Like in this image I have point inside smaller and coordinates are 2.5, 2.5. How I calculate its location in parent coordinates? Is there a pythonic way?

@GoodDeeds "And when you mean parent coordinates, do you mean scaled up by the ratio the parent is to the child?" Yes

[image: Location example]

Comment: @GoodDeeds Good points :) Updated image. Yes, scaled up by ratio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the coordinate system is fixed, and the image dimensions are parallel to the axes:

**1. Normalize the coordinates to [0, 1]:**

This tells you the fraction of the image covered by the coordinate along each dimension. This fraction remains constant when you scale up the image.

Given a coordinate `(x, y)`, and an image of dimensions `(w, h)`, the normalized coordinates are given by `(x/w, y/h)`. If the origin is not at `(0, 0)`, but at some `(x0, y0)`, it is given by `((x-x0)/w, (y-y0)/h)`.

**2. Scale up the coordinates**

Given a normalized coordinate `(x, y)`, for a parent image with dimensions `(W, H)`, the scaled coordinate will be `(x*W, y*H)`. If the origin is not at `(0, 0)`, but at some `(x0, y0)`, it is given by `(x*W+x0, y*H+y0)`.

---

Combining the two steps, since the origin for both images is the same at `(0, 0)`, and substituting `w = h = 5`, `W = H = 50`, for a coordinate `(x, y)`, the transformed coordinate `(x', y')` is given by:

`(x', y') = (50*x / 5, 50*y / 5) = (10*x, 10*y)`.

So, in your case, `(2.5, 2.5)` will be mapped to `(25, 25)`.